# Struggling with rewrite tactic in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, idris, theorem-proving

I'm going through Terry Tao's real analysis textbook, which builds up fundamental mathematics from the natural numbers up. By formalizing as many of the proofs as possible, I hope to familiarize myself with both Idris and dependent types.

I have defined the following datatype:

```
data GE: Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    Ge : (n: Nat) -> (m: Nat) -> GE n (n + m)
```

to represent the proposition that one natural number is greater than or equal to another.

I'm currently struggling to prove reflexivity of this relation, i.e. to construct the proof with signature

```
geRefl : GE n n
```

My first attempt was to simply try `geRefl {n} = Ge n Z`, but this has type `Ge n (add n Z)`. To get this to unify with the desired signature, we obviously have to perform some kind of rewrite, presumably involving the lemma

```
plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> left + fromInteger 0 = left
```

My best attempt is the following:

```
geRefl : GE n n                                                                 
geRefl {n} = x                                                                  
    where x : GE n (n + Z)                                                      
          x = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in Ge n Z
```

but this does not typecheck.

Can you please give a correct proof of this theorem, and explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: It would be much easier to make it `GE : (m : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> GE n (m + n)` instead.  Then `geRefl = GE Z`.

Comment: @RhubarbAndC I considered this, but it made other things harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is superficial: you are trying to apply the rewriting at the wrong place. If you have `x : GE n (n + Z)`, then you'll have to rewrite its type if you want to use it as the definition of `geRefl : GE n n`, so you'd have to write

```
geRefl : GE n n
geRefl {n} = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in x
```

But that still won't work. The real problem is you only want to rewrite a part of the type `GE n n`: if you just rewrite it using `n + 0 = n`, you'd get `GE (n + 0) (n + 0)`, which you still can't prove using `Ge n 0 : GE n (n + 0)`.

What you need to do is use the fact that if `a = b`, then `x : GE n a` can be turned into `x' : GE n b`. This is exactly what the `replace` function in the standard library provides:

```
replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y
```

Using this, by setting `P = GE n`, and using `Ge n 0 : GE n (n + 0)`, we can write `geRefl` as

```
geRefl {n} = replace {P = GE n} (plusZeroRightNeutral n) (Ge n 0)
```

(note that Idris is perfectly able to infer the implicit parameter `P`, so it works without that, but I think in this case it makes it clearer what is happening)